# How initialize std call into static const fields

Tags: c++, c++-cx

I have this code in header.

```
static property bool IsHighResolution
{
    bool get()
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER l;
        return QueryPerformanceFrequency(&l) != 0;
    }
}
```

Is there any way that I can cache result of `QueryPerformanceFrequency`? I'm just looking for better solution since the frequency of the performance counter is fixed at system boot.

Here is what I want.

```
private:
static LARGE_INTEGER _frequency; // how to make it read only or is it possible at all?
static bool _isHighres;

// somewhere in code, where gets executed only once.

_isHighres = QueryPerformanceFrequency(&_frequency);
```

I'm new to c++/cx and I cant really find solution to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about the initializer that comes with its definition?

Comment: I really appreciate any solution that caches the result. I'm c# programmer and totally new to c++ world. can you provide answer? @Quentin